# released from detention but not released?

Tags: california, legal-terms, detention

Context: I'm applying for US citizenship. I was arrested (so I think) a few years ago for misdemeanor.

The police took me on a Friday, I spent a night in "jail" (it might not be the correct technical term), and on Saturday the next day my friends found out about me and bailed me out.
I then took an attorney, who said she successfully worked on my case and that I was free. From there on nothing happened: I never heard from the court or the police again etc, and it was even impossible for the attorney to give me any formal confirmation from the court that I was "free".

This was 4 years ago, in California in Santa Clara county.

As I was gathering documents from the police and the court for the naturalization process, I see that I was detained but not arrested. Now looking at the dates on the document, it shows that I was **arrested and released on the same date**. But I was not released "in the nature" until my friends bailed me out the next day.

Questions:

- What does "release" mean?
- Why did I have to spend a night in jail if I was released?
- Technically, did I go to jail? or to a "detention facility"?
- Was I charged with committing, attempting to commit, or assisting in committing a crime or offense?
- Did I receive a suspended sentence?

If it can help, I couldn't find my name on Santa Clara's court: https://traffic.scscourt.org/search

Note: The first three questions are mine, the last two are asked in the naturalization questionnaire. It's a bit too technical for me to understand what is my situation.

Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a very important document. Even if we *did* give specific advice, you should not listen to random people on the internet, when you future/citizenship depends on it. Go get a lawyer.

Comment: Call the lawyer who worked on your case.

Comment: @bdb484 I suppose a better lawyer to call is an immigration lawyer who is familiar with California's criminal procedure.  This immigration lawyer ought to know how to the particulars of this incident relate to the questions in the naturalization application.  I'm fairly sure that there were no "charges" in this incident for the purpose of the fourth question, and there was surely no sentence, but, as you say, Thomas deserves more certainty in this than we can provide.

Comment: Thomas: "I see that I was detained but not arrested": if item (b) applies to you then you were "arrested without warrant."

Comment: Oh, but I see in item (c) "thereafter, the arrest shall not be deemed an arrest, but a detention only."  This is why you need an immigration lawyer.  It's possible that the incident isn't an arrest under California law but still is an arrest as far as immigration law is concerned.

Comment: @phoog thanks ; independently of the citizenship question, I'm really interested to know why I did not get released the same day. Any idea?

Comment: @Thomas I really don't know, other than the probably unsatisfying trivial answer that whatever circumstances caused them to be satisfied that there were insufficient grounds to charge you did not arise until after your friends bailed you out.